# How do I create a void * pointer using typeof at runtime

Tags: c++

```
#define test(p) (typeof(*(*p)) *)
```

The above macro is failing when `p` is of `void **` instead of something else.

It works in c but not in c++. Is there any round-about way to do this in c++?

Comment: I think you have to use something like dynamic_cast [check it out down the page](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/)

Comment: `typeof` "at runtime"? What exactly are you trying to test here? Just to check, this is with GCC?

Comment: Basically, when p is int **, I use that macro to do int * type casting. But it fails with error when p is void **.

Comment: Just use `typeof(*p)`. You're removing two * and adding one * back, so to speak. That indeed faisl for `void**` But it's indeed very braindead code.

Comment: No, I cant use typeof(*p), because this macro also need to ensure that p is a double pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++(11) there is [remove_pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer) which returns the type pointed to by the input type parameter.

> Basically, when p is int **, I use that macro to do int * type casting. But it fails with error when p is void **.[...] No, I cant use typeof(*p), because this macro also need to ensure that p is a double pointer.

If the cast is all you need a simple function template should help.

```
template<typename T>
T* remove_pointer_cast(T** p)
{
    return (T*)(p);
}
```